# Ionic5: Difference between "ionic build" and "ionic build --prod"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I have a problem while I build my Ionic5 app. The error comes from a custom component, which includes a plugin (ionic4-auto-complete)

If I'm building for production (ionic build --prod), I always get the following error:

```
src/app/components/skill-autocomplete/skill-autocomplete.component.html:42:7 - error NG8001: 'ion-label' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-label' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-label' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

If I build it without flags (ionic build), it works and I get no errors.

The strangeness is, that the module of the named custom component (and every other module too) already has IonicModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA and NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA imported. So I don't understand why I get this error?

That's the whole annotation of the module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SkillAutocompleteComponent,
    AutoCompleteComponent,
    SkillsModalPage,
    BoldPrefix
  ],
  imports: [CommonModule, IonicModule],
  exports: [SkillAutocompleteComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
```

Do you have some ideas, why that only appears with flags? I thought, that the flag "--prod" is just for another environment and optimizes the code?

Thank you in advance and stay healthy
m.

Comment: also add `BrowserModule` in your imports array.  `import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';` inside `app.module.ts` file

Comment: I believe adding the `--prod` flag sets the linting of the code to be more strict, which may be why you are seeing these errors only when you try and compile with that command.

Comment: @zeropsi is correct. You can learn more here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#production-optimizations

Comment: Do you have more than one module? Do you have any spec.ts tests that are being run? You really shouldn't be needing any schemas if you're importing correctly.

Comment: sorry for my late reply.The BrowserModule I have already imported in my app.module.ts. I read the guide, but that doesn't help really.

@Porter Lyman: Yes I have more than one, and in every module I already imported the schema, but it doesn't help.